# What is the namespace environment for .SD and other similar special variables of data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I know that in R, if the variable is not defined within a function, it will be searched upstream. So I thought that it should be true for special `data.table` variables, like `.SD`, `.N` etc. But this code doesn't work:

```
data(iris)
setDT(iris)

myFunA <- function(){
  return(nrow(.SD))
}

iris[,myFunA(),by=Species]
```

Is there any way to reach `.SD` from within the function, without passing it as an argument like `myFunA(.SD)`? (yes I know it's generally not a good practice but for this use case I'd connive at it)

Comment: The short answer is: no, you cannot. The long answer is, you might be able to fudge something to work, but I recommend against it.

Comment: Elaborating a little bit more, I think you have the function design wrong. `.SD` is a shorthand for "the data for this group". So you should write a function that takes "some data" as input, rather than having it essentially rely on a global variable.

Comment: yes my intent was to write the function that will work with "data for this group", so it would be called for each `by=` group. It's purely aesthetical question: I wanted to see `myDT[,myFunction(),by=grpCol]` instead of `myDT[,myFunction(.SD, .GRP),by=grpCol]` for example. It's not a big deal that I had to get back to the latter form, but I'm just curious on the mechanism why those variables are not accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that .SD, while accessible, is not filled in at the point that myFunA is run.  .N is usable though as in myFunB below so the particular example in the question could be modified as in myFunB to work.

The problem seems to be that data.table optimizes the calculation to avoid filling in .SD if it thinks it is not used.  If we do use it then it can be made to work as in myFunC below.

```
library(data.table)
irisDT <- as.data.table(iris)

myFunA <- function(envir = parent.frame()) with(envir, .SD)
irisDT[, myFunA(), by = Species]
## Empty data.table (0 rows and 1 cols): Species

myFunB <- function(envir = parent.frame()) with(envir, .N)
irisDT[, myFunB(), by = Species]
##       Species V1
## 1:     setosa 50
## 2: versicolor 50
## 3:  virginica 50

myFunC <- function(envir = parent.frame()) with(envir, nrow(.SD))
irisDT[, {.SD; myFunC()}, by = Species]
##       Species V1
## 1:     setosa 50
## 2: versicolor 50
## 3:  virginica 50
```